# How can i automate killing processes labeled "Waiting" in MySQL with simple line of bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, mysql

I was trying to run following bash line without success, i've tried many variants of the same line without success, hope somebody see the error.

```
mysql -u user --password=\m\y\p\a\s\s  -h myhost -e 'kill $(mysql -u user --password=\m\y\p\a\s\s -h myhost -e "show processlist;" | grep Waiting | awk '{print $1}' )'
```

Basically inside $(...) i'm doing a list of processes in status Waiting and outside that code i'm trying to kill such processes, this is a bash question with $() code that is why i'm posting it here, and i guess there is something with quotes, but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are too strong.

Really.

`'`s are "strong" quotes, which is to say that parameter expansions, subshell expansions, history expansions, and the like do not work within them.

```
$ echo '$(echo foo)'
$(echo foo)
$ echo "$(echo foo)"
foo
```